# Creating custom redirect list - asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect

Where would I start... to do the following.

**Add**/ **Update**/ **Delete** Custom redirects for asp.net mvc

I understand how to use the entity framework to build my models/views and controllers but I'm unsure where I how I should handle a list of redirects. I want control over where non-exsistant controllers resolve to.

I can do this manually using the global but I want authenticated admins to be able to control this.

**Example:**

/home/contactus   **>**   /anotherControler/Action

/home/about  **>**  http://championscentre.com/

etc...

Answer (score 0):

I think this logic is most appropriately done with the IIS7's URL rewriting module. If that is not an option and you need to have this built into the web interface, I think you need the following steps:

1. Create a catch all route that accepts one string parameter and sends it to a controller that handles the redirects.
2. Have your controller action find the URL string in the database and select the associated redirect URL.
3. Handle the redirect in the action.

The problem with any approach like this is you won't be able to use various HTML helpers for these "routes".